Understanding the details of equality in Python
When trying to construct an example where a == b is not the same as b == a, it seems that I have accidentally constructed an example where a == b is not the same as a.__eq__(b):
class A:

    def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
        return type(other) is A


class B(A):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    b = B()
    assert not a.__eq__(b)  # as expected
    assert not (a == b)  # Why does this fail?

Can somebody explain to me why the last assertion fails? I expected it to be the same as the second one.

Because b.__eq__(a)

Does this answer your question? Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?

@toyotaSupra I suspect they already know the difference, they were performing an experiment.

@toyotaSupra No, to be honest, it doesn't.

@mousetail Just to be sure that I understand your comment: Do you claim that a == b is evaluated to a.__eq__(b) or b.__eq__(a)? If yes, do you have a reference?

@SebastianThomas Seems to be a special case if one class is a subclass of the other, then only the subclasses __eq__ will be used

@mousetail But B.__eq__ is the same as A.__eq__, isn't it?

Yes, but now other is a, which is of type A making __eq__ True.

@SebastianThomas Yes, but (see matszwecja's answer) the arguments are flipped. a == b, because B is a subclass of A, gets implemented as b.__eq__(a), not a.__eq__(b).

As a side note, equality is supposed to be symmetric; don't give it a definition that is sensitive to the order of the arguments (and certainly don't ignore self in the definition).

@chepner Thanks, I know that. I was trying to explicitly make a non-sense definition that was supposed to be not symmetric.

The relevant quote explaining what happens is located in the documentation:

If the operands are of different types, and the right operand’s type is a direct or indirect subclass of the left operand’s type, the reflected method of the right operand has priority, otherwise the left operand’s method has priority. Virtual subclassing is not considered.


Specifically, a == b is turned into b.__eq__(a), not a.__eq__(b).

If you give B its own version of __eq__() and put print statements in each, it's easy to demonstrate that a == b is actually evaluated as b.__eq__(a).  No, I don't know why it's done in the opposite of how I would naively expect.

Seems to happen only if B is a subclass

When two objects in Python are compared, the Python interpeter uses the do_richcompare operation which is written in C.  See here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.3/Objects/object.c#L717
In the C code, one of the first checks is for subtyping.
do_richcompare(PyObject *v, PyObject *w, int op)
{
    richcmpfunc f;
    PyObject *res;
    int checked_reverse_op = 0;

    if (v->ob_type != w->ob_type &&
        PyType_IsSubtype(w->ob_type, v->ob_type) &&
        (f = w->ob_type->tp_richcompare) != NULL) {
        checked_reverse_op = 1;
        res = (*f)(w, v, _Py_SwappedOp[op]);
        if (res != Py_NotImplemented)
            return res;
        Py_DECREF(res);
    }

This basically says if you are using the comparison:
v == w

But, the type of w is a subclass of the type of v, then return
w == v

which is equivalent of w.__eq__(v)
Or in this specific case, calling:
a == b

will return
b == a

because B is a subclass A
